# Magento 1.9.2 - Translation for subcategories not work

Tags: magento-1.9, category, language

I have a problem with my subcategories listed in the category page. My site is in Italian and in English. But when I put the language in Italian it translates around the site but no for subcategories. Why?

This is the link: http://store.gadgetlab.it/estate/

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you renamed your subcategories in the italian store view?

Comment: Yes. In fact, in the backend I see correctly the translation, but does not work in the frontend

Comment: hm, it's not just the name, the links are also wrong. Have you reindexed and flushed cache?

Comment: Yes, i reindexed and flushed cache but ever with the same result. How can i do?

Comment: Do you use a module for vertical menu?

Comment: I use a block for this and i reclaim my custom file in catalog.xml: <block type="core/template" name="catalog.sidenav" template="page/custom.phtml" before="cart_sidebar"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45414/discussion-between-yiorgos-moschovitis-and-gabriel91).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The cause of the incorrect code was inserted in the head to generate hreflang for all magento pages.

Thanks for the help ;)